# How to print previous page data to current page in php?

Tags: php, html

How to show NAME field data in the current page, which are entered by the user in the login page?
**Details**

1.User will enter username and password in the below page which is saved as "home.html".

```
<form action="indexpage.php" method="post">
<p>Username</p> 
<input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername" required>
<p>Password</p>
<input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"required></br>
<button><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/webiconset/application/32/Register-icon.png"  /></button>
</form>
```

2.After hitting login button this will redirect to this page(below is the script) and saved as "indexpage.php".

```
<html>
<form method="post" action="insert1.php">
<div style="text-align:center">
<button>INSERT<img src="http://brandonmadeawebsite.com/images/art/icons/insert_icon.png"  height="30" /></button> </div>
</form>
</html>
```

3.Now if i select insert option from the option it will redirect to "insert1.php" page

```
<p>
<label>ENTER NAME</label>
<input type="text"  name="name"  value="<?php print $myusername;    ?>" required>
```

Here I am trying to print USERNAME field, immediately after entering to this page.
Kindly help me out, Thanks in advance

Comment: You could save this data into `session` and later use it on other page through `$_SESSION`

Comment: when you send your formular data to "indexpage.php" the data will be saved in `$_POST` array. so you can access the username via `$_POST['myusername']` for example

Answer (score 1):

Without session technique

You could change the code of **indexpage.php**

```
<html>
<form method="post" action="insert1.php">
<div style="text-align:center">
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $_POST['username'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="password" value="<?php echo $_POST['password'] ?>">
<button>INSERT<img src="http://brandonmadeawebsite.com/images/art/icons/insert_icon.png"  height="30" /></button> </div>
</form>
</html>
```

Now the values from first form are available for 3rd form to submit

and  on third page

```
<label>ENTER NAME</label>
<input type="text"  name="name"  value="<?php print $_POST['username'];    ?>" required>
```

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: its not printing the name in insert1.php page.

Comment: its not printing name in the index1.php page

Comment: Not to be rude @MeeneshJain but update your own answer ?

Comment: change `myusername` to `username` on third page

Comment: @Pogrindis no problem... i just asked out of curiosity.. and as a help

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a session, and save your username when a user are log :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username']= $youreval;
```

and when you want to use it dont forget to put this in your script (on top) :

```
session_start();
```

Comment: When you are in a login page it's a good idea to start using session, he can use $_POST if needed, but it's better to use session so he can reuse the username on every page not only the page+1

Comment: Im not sure why this is downvoted, it **IS** an option